# Would there be any benefit to writing synchronous code using the syntax of promises

Tags: javascript

Is there such a concept as a synchronous promise? Would there be any benefit to writing synchronous code using the syntax of promises?

```
try {
  foo();
  bar(a, b);
  bam();
} catch(e) {
  handleError(e);
}
```

...could be written something like (but using a synchronous version of `then`);

```
foo()
  .then(bar.bind(a, b))
  .then(bam)
  .fail(handleError)
```

Comment: Oh god no please don't do this, it's harder to debug, introduces asynchronisity to synchronous code and can't be "escaped". http://stackoverflow.com/q/28937788/1348195 which you also asked is the better of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely!  For several reasons:

- Promises provide an excellent error checking system.  You can return a promise and let the caller deal with the promise however he or she wishes (or not at all).
- Many would argue that promises make your code cleaner and easier to read, which is no small thing.  I would argue that promises are worth using if for no other reason than the fact that it is elegant.
- Last, but certainly not least, your implementation *now* is synchronous but should that ever change, you don't have to change a big section of code in order to make synchronous work asynchronously, but just the actual implementation.

Now, please don't get me wrong, I don't think you should use promises for every thing you do in the program, though for something that is even mildly cpu-intensive or complicated, I would get into the habit of using promises to implement these operations.

The main drawback is that promises are not fully supported in older browsers, so if you decide to go this route, consider using some polyfill library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) to make it work both in newer browsers as well as older browsers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Promises aren't inherently implemented functions in the first place. Your answer seems to suggest that newer runtimes will automatically support the promise syntax. Only functions that return promises will support the promise-sequencing syntax. Even with ES6 one must work with a promise strategy.

Comment: @stimpy77 I don't quite understand how you derived that conclusion.  If you're using bluebird or q, you can simply choose to not update your library if you don't want problems caused by "newer runtimes that no longer support promise-sequencing syntax."  That said, this is a bit like saying that you shouldn't use functions in javascript because future ecma versions may no longer have the same syntax.  I think you're fairly safe on that front, at least for the immediate future.

Comment: I'm not "deriving" any "conclusions". Promises are a pattern. If you use bluebird or $.Deferred or anything else, you're utilizing implementations of the pattern. But Javascript functions do not automatically implement promises. I'm not suggesting anyone shouldn't do anything. Just stating reality, which is that Bluebird or some other lib isn't a "polyfill". You still have to implement the pattern, even if you use ES6's implementation of the pattern. In other words there's a lot going on in x.then(y).then(z).fail(f), which is that these functions must return promises. I'd still encourage it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Your code sample will fail on ..

```
.then(bar.bind(a, b))
```

You'd have to use

```
.then(function() {bar.bind(a,b);})
```

.. unless foo()'s resolve() returns the arguments a,b in which case you'd use ..

```
.then(bar.bind)
```

In any case, the real advantage of writing that code in that way is that it really isn't synchronous code. It's sequential, but not synchronous. It's asynchronous. The `foo()` invocation could invoke some filesystem activity that takes a while, if running on node.js/io.js, or it could run a background worker in a separate thread if running on a modern browser, and in either case the promise wouldn't `resolve()` and the next `then()` wouldn't execute until that task completes, but meanwhile Javascript's main thread is still running and processing other events.

The down side is that you must have a promise strategy in place and work with it. Where Neil said you should use a polyfill, which is true in that ECMAScript 6 isn't generally adopted yet, even if it was you must still work with its promise strategy. So your greater concern is that `foo()` and `bar()` and `bam()` must return promises. Those promises must be objects that intercept a `resolve()` or `reject()` and pass them on to `.then()` or `.done()` and to `.fail()`, and they must chain for `.fail()`. (There's more to promises than this, you'll need to do more research on this if you bake your own.) The existing promise frameworks including even jQuery's `$.Deferred` are pretty elegant but the point is you're adding more work to your code.

So, really as Neil said you should only write your code in the promises syntax manner when you feel you're sequentially invoking methods that are expected to be long-running tasks. However, YAGNI; don't do it if you think they might be long-running tasks in the future, only do it if you know they're long-running tasks now. Don't optimize early until you've identified a bottleneck. But you also must consider the cost of promises. Don't write asynchronous code if you can't handle supporting the promise strategy.